# What is the generic name for classes that are not the "main" class?

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point, terminology

The "main" class marks the entry point of the program, often instantiating other classes in its main method. Is there a generic name for the classes that are not the "main" class?

I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to learn more about its terminology and haven't been able to find this information anywhere.

Comment: There's no term for that.

Comment: Just "class"...?

Comment: I just call them "classes".

Comment: While there is no widely accepted terminology for the classes with/without main methods, The classes with a main method would generally be referred to as Main classes, Application, Program or Launcher classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The "main" class marks the entry point of the program, often instantiating other classes in its main method. Is there a generic name for the classes that are not the "main" class?

There is no standard "main" class. Or non-main. There are just classes.

There may be some classes that have a method with signature `public static void main(String[] args)`.
These classes are executable with `java package.TheClassName` on the command line, or can be the designated main class declared in executable `jar` files.
Often there is one such class in a project,
but there can be as many as you want.
There's no standard naming for these classes.
(I call them runners.)

Package authors have to explicitly document the package and name of these classes so that users can run them, because there's no standard way to guess them.
Or else a runner script or an executable jar is provided to encapsulate the detail of the name (and parameters).
Either way, the method of execution must always be documented, because it's not obvious.

> I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to learn more about its terminology and haven't been able to find this information anywhere.

That's because there's nothing to find.

Answer (score 1):

There is no recognized term for a class that is not an entry-point class.  It is not a concept that requires<sup>1</sup> a specific term.  That is why you can't find one.

As an analogy: there is no recognized scientific term for all animals that are not pandas either.

---

Solutions:

- Refer to such a class as "a non-main class", and people will know what you mean<sup>2</sup>.
- Use formal logic / mathematical notation.  Mathematicians have been able to express themselves clearly / concisely for hundreds of years :-)

---

<sup>1 - That is, the concept does not come up often enough in informal discourse / conversation to warrant someone proposing term for it.</sup>

<sup>2 - In other words, improvise.  Just like you would when you were trying to describe some other concept that you don't know the word for.</sup>